# Stored procedure that exports data into csv files only exports to one file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a fun script:

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE
DECLARE @MinDOS DATE
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = 'ViewAccountDetail'
SELECT @MinDOS = MIN(dos) FROM accn_demographics
SELECT @StartDT = 
    CAST(CAST(datepart(YYYY,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST('01' AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @FileLocation VARCHAR(50)

WHILE @StartDT < '20110901'
BEGIN
    SET @FileLocation='C:\test\'+@TableName+cast(@StartDT as varchar)+'.csv'
    EXEC BCP_Text_File @TableName, @FileLocation    
    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)
END
```

It is supposed to do is export data into csv files. The names of the files should be:

```
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-01-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-02-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-03-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-04-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-05-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-06-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-07-01.csv
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-08-01.csv
```

but it stores all the data into the same one:

```
C:\test\ViewAccountDetail2011-01-01.csv
```

i did a `print @FileLocation` and confirmed that it correctly updates this variable.

is there any apparent, OBVIOUS thing that i am missing here?

FYI this line:

```
EXEC BCP_Text_File @TableName, @FileLocation
```

calls this procedure:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BCP_Text_File]
    @table    NVARCHAR(255),  
    @filename VARCHAR(100)  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF OBJECT_ID(@table) IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @cols += ',' + name
      FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table)
      ORDER BY column_id;

    SELECT @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '');

    SET @sql = N'EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT ''''' 
        + REPLACE(@cols, ',', ''''',''''') + ''''' UNION ALL SELECT ' 
        + 'RTRIM(' + REPLACE(@cols, ',', '),RTRIM(') + ') FROM ' 
        + DB_NAME() + '..' + @table + '" queryout "' + @filename + '" -c -T''';  

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'The table '+@table+' does not exist in the database';
  END
END

GO
```

thank you so much for your help and guidance!!

Comment: Re-write this line  as `SET @FileLocation='C:\test\'+@TableName+convert(varchar(20),@StartDT)+'.csv'`

Comment: Try reducing your code to just a few lines that really get to the core of the problem and don't require any calls to external procedures. Then we can try running the code for ourselves. If I'm going to debug this I want something I can copy+paste into SSMS and run without getting any errors, missing tables, missing stored procedures, etc. In other words, make it a simple, self-contained example that reproduces your error.

Comment: try to change this one too `SET @StartDT = DATEADD(month,1,@StartDT)`

Comment: I have an answer, and SO errors every time I try to post it... This code, as it is, works for me. The dates stuff works fine @CoDeaDDict, and the files are all created with identical data (the full contents of the table sent into the sproc). Are you sure you're running the code you gave?

Comment: When I substitute "SELECT @MinDOS = '20110101'" for "MIN(dos) FROM accn_demographics", I get the desired result, so you may start by looking at the value returned by accn_demographics.

Comment: No, I am just guessing @JeremyPridemore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me. I have a few suggestions:

(1) stop doing all that string concatenation to build a date. You can do the same thing much easier as in:

```
SELECT @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @MinDOS), '19000101');
```

(2) [stop declaring `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). And to ensure the right output, I prefer convert:

```
SET @FileLocation = 'C:\test\' + @TableName
   + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDT, 120) + '.csv';
```

(3) instead of "debugging" the code by running the stored procedure and inspecting the output in the folder, why not sanity-check your input first? Also, why use two variables for the date?

```
DECLARE 
   @StartDT DATE, 
   @TableName NVARCHAR(50), 
   @FileLocation VARCHAR(255);

SET @TableName = N'ViewAccountDetail';

SELECT @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', MIN(dos)), '19000101')
   FROM dbo.accn_demographics;

   PRINT @StartDT;
-- ^^^^^ debugging 101 - what month do we think we're starting at?

WHILE @StartDT < '20110901'
BEGIN
    SET @FileLocation = 'C:\test\' + @TableName
      + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDT, 120) + '.csv';

      PRINT @FileLocation;
    --^^^^^ again, debugging 101 - what does the filename currently look like?

    --EXEC BCP_Text_File @TableName, @FileLocation    
    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDT);
END
```